# Unable to invoke getStore in Secha Touch application

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to setup a localStorage to save the Authentication Token received from my REST service, but unfortunately i keep getting the error that functions related to the store does not exist:

> TypeError: Ext.getStore is not a function
>
> var test = Ext.getStore('myPhysioStorage');

**My implementation**:

store/UserStore.js

```
Ext.define('Physio.model.UserStore'), {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'sessiontoken'
        ]
    }
});
```

model/UserStore.js

```
Ext.define('Physio.store.UserStore'), {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'Physio.model.UserStore',
    
    config: {
        model: 'Physio.model.UserStore',
        autoload: true,
        storeId: 'myPhysioStorage',
        
        proxy: {
            type: 'localStorage',
            id: 'myPhysioStorageProxy'
        }
    }
});
```

controller/Login.js

```
...
launch: function() {
    var test = Ext.getStore('myPhysioStorage');
    console.log(userStore);
}
...
```

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Physio',
    views: ['Login','MainMenu'],
    controllers:['Login','MainMenu'],
    store:['UserStore'],
    model:['UserStore'],
    launch: function () {
        
        Ext.Viewport.add([
            { xtype: 'loginview' },
            { xtype: 'mainmenuview' }
        ]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included your `app.js` and the sencha touch lib `sencha-touch.js` in your html page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/sencha-touch/sencha-touch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
```

Have you also added `Ext.data.Store` in the requires attribute in your `Ext.application`?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'name',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Store', 'some more'
    ],
....
});
```

Comment: The `requires` was missing in `app.js`.